# Android | Update sqlite from mysql or update app with newer sqlite db?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

Still newish to Android.
I need some advise, Should I 
 1. have a local sqlite DB, and have the app check for new records uptop in a mysql DB
OR
 2. Publish my app with a full sqlite DB. When ever I insert new records to the full sql lite DB then publish updates?

I've been scouring the internet for some guidance. Since I am still newer to Android I wonder the difficulty in making #1 work (since I'll have to gen the php code as well).

Comment: What size is your DB?

Comment: 17.9 KB total (Currently)
1 Table, 12 rows, 200 Records and counting atm... I am still scrubbing the data to populate my mysqlDB.

expected at least 16,000 records

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is:

1. If it's only 200 records now, it doesn't really matter if you preload it or get it from a web service (getting the data will be very quick). Usually preloaded database is better when there is a lot of data and you don't want the user to wait to long before using your App.
   On the other hand if there is a lot of data, it will increase the apk size.
2. Create a web service method for updating the data from the server.
3. Create a web service method which indicate the client to delete some rows (I dont know what your application does, but usually it's needed)

Comment: Are their any good tutorials for CRUD operations between your mysql db and your local sqlite db?

This is kind of where I always run into problems...

Comment: As I see it, the CRUD operations are as this:
1. Web Service - get tha data from MySql using standard CRUD operations.
2. Parse the results into XML/JSON (preferably JSON)
3. Fetch the data from the client and update it using Sqlite CRUD.

The CRUD isn't really between the Sqlite and MySql, as you have the web service in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'uptop'? Assuming you mean 'online via an API'.

depending on the nature of your data (is is mission critical? what's the risks if it is stale? etc), it's good practice to pack static data with the app that can be referenced by the app much sooner than the updated data...the updated data is a task you run to update that stale data, and perhaps continue to run periodically to keep it updated.

It's bad practice to pack a SQLite db itself in an app, as some manufacturers do their own thing with the implementation of SQLite itself. So pack the SQL as text and create a fresh DB on the device with that.

Comment: uptop = online in phpmyadmin

The data will not go Stale as its historic data. We will be just adding NEW records. Such as "what colors did a 1983 Alfa Romero GTV-6 come in?"

Comment: I'd suggest, as Udi l did too, to create an API that interfaces with your MySQL DB, providing results to the app in JSON. You don't want to be providing apps with DB authentication information! Since it is historical data, pack as much as you can and makes sense in terms of user experience + apk size.